# Firestore: cant delete document

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

this is my function for deleting a document in my "files" collection

```dart
Future<void> deleteProgram(String id, String program) async {
    try {
      print(id + "----" + program);
      await firestoreInstance.collection("files").doc(program).delete();
      // await firestoreInstance.collection("programs").doc(id).delete();
      print("done");
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }  
  }
```

program is the id of the document, when i use this nothing gets deleted, even if i hardcode the ID.

this is what my collection looks like:
[image]

as you can see, each document in the files collection also has a subcollection called files

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: you have to delete subcollections too, when you delete a doc , the subCollection will not be deleted

Comment: @Anna how do i delete a subcollection at once instead of deleting each file in the subcollection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to delete a collection is to delete each individual document from it. There is no atomic operation to delete a collection.

In your screenshot the *opleiding4* is shown in italic, meaning that this document doesn't really exist, and the Firebase console merely shows that name to be able to show its `files` subcollection.

Once you delete all files from the `/files/opeleiding4/files` subcollection both that collection and its parent document will disappear from the Firebase console too.

Also see:

- [Firestore DB - documents shown in italics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137582/firestore-db-documents-shown-in-italics)
- [How to recursively delete collection in firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66013255/how-to-recursively-delete-collection-in-firestore)
- [How to Delete all documents in collection in Firestore with Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53089517/how-to-delete-all-documents-in-collection-in-firestore-with-flutter)